# Add custom header react-infinite-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

How can I add a custom header component to [react-infinite-calendar](https://github.com/clauderic/react-infinite-calendar)?
It seems the package doesn't have that kinda support(unsure though).

Is there any way I can insert a button component inside the header?

expected output: [image]

basic calendar initialization:

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-fire-npsq7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `HeaderComponent` prop to pass custom header to react-infinite-calendar. You can use the following code in your codesandbox example.

```
import "./styles.css";
import InfiniteCalendar from 'react-infinite-calendar'
import 'react-infinite-calendar/styles.css' 
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InfiniteCalendar
        width={400}
        height={600}
        HeaderComponent={() => <p>123</p>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```